# Create a Yosemite-like UI in Interface Builder

Tags: macos, user-interface, interface-builder

I'm trying to work on a Markdown app for macOS and iOS that works more closely with Jekyll, especially in use with GitHub Pages. I have a general idea for an interface and I know a bit of Swift, but I am experiencing issues when trying to create the interface for the macOS version. I want to create an interface that best works with macOS Yosemite or higher, but the Interface Builder in Xcode doesn't seem to let me do that. For reference, I have a linked image of Bear, which has a similar design that I want to do:

[Bear screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSiJE.png)

While I am able to find parts in documentation and other parts of Stack Overflow regarding using the transparency programmatically, I am still unable to figure out how to get the master-detail view in the "Yosemite" style, as seen in the image. I've looked in Apple's documentation and other websites, and after some researching, I can't seem to find the right answer to this question.

How do I achieve this master-detail view, or just creating an app in Interface Builder that pertains to recent macOS versions' UI, not something from OS X Mountain Lion or below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pre-made "master-detail" view component in Interface Builder.

You have to use `NSVisualEffectView` together with `NSTableView` and programmatically exchange views in a container `NSView`.

Relevant API's:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsvisualeffectview
https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstableview